# Angular/AngularJs hybrid deep linking

Tags: angular

I can not get deep linking to work with a angular/angualrjs hybrid app. see example:

https://run.plnkr.co/2NBTzJstM25istaq/#/users

```
(source: https://plnkr.co/edit/03l5iA?p=preview).
```

The example should navigate to the users route but doesn't. Any suggestions how to enable deep linking?